# Расстановка запятых при однородных членах с союзом "и"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Вот предложение:

> И в том и в этом мире, и люди и ангелы - все мы разрушаем красоту.

Не знаю, как правильно расставить запятые.

Comment: Ангелов-то за что записали в разрушители? У них задача иная, и только одна.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В ответе справочной службы русского языка gramota.ru сказано:

```
Как правило, сочетание типа *и те и другие* запятой не разделяется.
```

Дальнейший же повтор союзов отбивается запятой, поэтому первая часть предложения будет такой: «И в том и в этом мире и люди, и ангелы — ...».

Тире ставится, как замена слову *значит*.

Answer (score 1):

**И в том и в этом мире, и люди и ангелы — все мы разрушаем красоту.**

Правила позволяют объединять однородные члены, связанные повторяющимся союзом И...И, если они тесно связаны по смыслу. В этом случае запятая не ставится, сочетание произносится  без паузы.

Распространенный оборот в начале  предложения, отнесенный к местоимению, обособляется тире.

Именно такая расстановка знаков обеспечивает удобное произношение предложения.

Comment: Как Вы обоснуете запятую между парами однородных членов? Неужели только произношением? Примечание: я думаю, можно    это предложение отредактировать так, что Ваша запятая будет уместна, но не уверен в том, что смог бы ее защитить.

Comment: Здесь пропущено обобщающее обстоятельство: И в том и в этом мире, и люди и ангелы — все мы  (и в обоих мирах) разрушаем красоту. Предложение нестандартное, первая часть задает тему (состоящую из двух частей), которая раскрывается во второй части. Другая постановка знаков будет затемнять смысл предложения, вот что главное.

Comment: Все равно не очень понятно.  Зайдем с другой стороны.  "Все мы и в обоих мирах" — что здесь звязано союзом И?

Comment: Лучше так зайдем: Все мы,  и в обоих мирах - присоединение, а не соединение.

Answer (score 0):

У нас две пары однородных членов предложения, при этом между парами нет отношения однородности, поэтому запятая между парами не нужна, тем более, что обобщаюшие слова "все мы" относятся только ко второй паре. В первой паре запятая не ставится.

> Не ставится запятая в цельных фразеологизированных сочетаниях с повторяющимися союзами (они соединяют слова с противоположными значениями). Ваши примеры подпадают под это правило. (http://slovari.ru/default.aspx?s=0&p=1160)

**И в том и в этом мире и люди, и ангелы — все мы разрушаем красоту.**

Примечания. К предложенной фразе у меня немало вопросов. Вот лишь некоторые из них.

- Что за ситуация, в которой кто-то может сказать "мы" о людях и ангелах вместе?
- Что это за ангелы, разрушающие красоту?
- Если тот мир — это загробный мир, то как представить себе разрушение красоты, происходащее в нем?
- И люди и ангелы действуют в обоих мирах? Если нет, то предложение надо бы изменить.

Если люди соответствуют этому миру, а ангелы — тому, то, без обобщающих слов "все мы", можно было бы написать, например, такую фразу:  "Красоту разрущают и в этом мире и в том, и люди и ангелы". Здесь другая логика: вторая пара авляется как бы уточняющей констукцией, она отделяется запятoй, а симметрия двух пар и тесная связь в каxдой паре позволяет не разделять пары запятыми.

Comment: Вы это можете произнести? "И в том и в этом мире и люди, и ангелы — все мы разрушаем красоту". Обстоятельство к первому однородному члену отнесете.?

Comment: @Ксения "Как Вы это можете произнести?". Ответ: для того, чтобы при  чтении сделать паузу, необязательно видеть в тексте  запятую. Если запятую нельзя ставить по правилам, то это не запрет на паузу. "Обстоятельство к первому однородному члену отнесете?" Ответ: Фраза сама по себе очень спорная, мягко выражаясь, если читать как написано, то  и люди и ангелы действуют в обоих мирах, то есть обстоятельство относится к  обоим подлежащим.

Comment: Знаки препинания должны ПОМОГАТЬ правильному прочтению и пониманию текста (особенно нестандартного),  это их основное назначение, в то время как нам иногда кажется, что их главная задача - это СООТВЕТСТВОВАТЬ правилам. А предложение действительно нестандартное, но грамматика у него интересная. Первая часть мне напоминает именительный темы, только вместо местоимения "это" используется местоимение "мы". Грамматика  и структура мне нравятся, а содержание я не могу понять из одного предложения, для этого нужен контекст.